# how do i redirect based on selection in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, web

My form is :

```
<div>
    <form name="redirect">
        <select name="selection">
            <option value="">--------service--------</option>
            <option value="plumber.jsp">PLUMBER</option>
            <option value="electrician.jsp">ELECTRICIAN</option>
            <option value="carpenter.jsp">CARPENTER</option>
        </select>
        <select name="locality">
            <option value="">--------select--------</option>
            <option value="KOMMADI">KOMMADI</option>
            <option value="MVP">MVP</option>
            <option value="RTC">RTC</option>
        </select>
        <input type=submit value="Go!" onClick="WinOpen();">  
    </form>
```

and the javascript is

```
<script language="javascript">
    function WinOpen() {
        var url = document.redirect.selection.value;
        document.location.href = url; 
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }             
</script>
```

The above code is not working for me. The page just refreshes instead of redirecting. I want to redirect to page based on the selection value and also send the locality parameter to the other page.

Comment: Are you redirecting to a specific page with the selected value as a query string parameter?

Comment: actually based on the selection the redirection to which page is decided.

Comment: i am giving the url of the page for redirection

Comment: Maybe you can link to some documentation that says `response.sendRedirect()` is valid javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript like this.It will assign value of selection to the action attribute of form.

```
 <script language="javascript">
    function WinOpen() 
    {
        document.redirect.action = document.redirect.selection.value;
        document.redirect.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

It should work.

One more thing,you can access your locality paramter on the destination jsp by

```
String locality=request.getParameter("locality");
```